# Load levels dynamically in android game as3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, 2d-games

I'm developing Android game app with more levels using Flash. I want to know How to handle the levels and to load without performance issue. The game has heavy designs and animations so that I cannot keep everything in frame. Please give suggestions

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, XML is the best route to go. ActionScript 3 has built-in functions to parse read strings into XML typed variables. Libraries exists for JSON as well - both will cost extra resource.

Store your level data like this

```
1,1,0,2,1,4,2
0,1,3,2,0,0,2
4,2,2,3,0,3,4
```

Parse the level file and split the string by commas, or whatever character you're using to separate the level variables.

var levels:Array = levelFile.split(",");

Comment: user3932026 Thanks for the reply. How can I handle the Graphics assets? Can you post any tutorials for this.

Comment: Is it possible by using Flash CS6?